# Parameterized sub-flow

Tags: mule

Is it possible to create a parameterized sub-flow in Mule?  I have to do the same complex process twice, almost exactly the same, with a few minor differences.  Is the best way to do this to set a bunch of flow variables in advance of the flow reference and then use those variables in the flow I want to parameterize, or is there simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a correct direction.  IF you have a same piece of functionality you want to operate with different set's of data, go with sub-flows. The approach you have mentioned works and it is the best possible I can see.